# jQuery array sort works on only first table element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one table which is being sorted by clicking on a header field and another which isn't. The table which is working comes before the one that doesn't sort, if the order is a factor.

The first table sorts and the second doesn't.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Josh_T/gyfoousf/4/)

```js
$('th').each(function(col) {

  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.asc')) {
      $(this).removeClass('asc');
      $(this).addClass('desc selected');
      sortOrder = -1;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('asc selected');
      $(this).removeClass('desc');
      sortOrder = 1;
    }
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('asc selected');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('desc selected');
    var arrData = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr:has(td)').get();

    arrData.sort(function(a, b) {
      //console.log(a, b);
      var val1 = $(a).find('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
      var val2 = $(b).find('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
      if ($.isNumeric(val1) && $.isNumeric(val2))
        return sortOrder == 1 ? val1 - val2 : val2 - val1;
      else
        return (val1 < val2) ? -sortOrder : (val1 > val2) ? sortOrder : 0;
    });
    //$(this).closest('tbody tr').remove()
    $.each(arrData, function(index, row) {
      //console.log(row);
      $(this).closest('tbody').append(row);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: none !important;
}

table th {
  border: none !important;
}

table td {
  border: none;
}

table thead th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table thead tr td {
  padding-right: 2em;
}

table tbody {
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

table thead tr th:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="leaderboard">

  <thead>

    <tr>

      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>00:15:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
      <td>01:00:13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
      <td>03:00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
      <td>08:00:00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<table id="leaderboard2">

  <thead>

    <tr>

      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>00:17:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
      <td>00:20:35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Alice</td>
      <td>23:19:18</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I recommend using https://datatables.net/ for sortable tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How much network overhead does that dependency require?

Comment: You are welcome. Aprox. 90-100 KB. It has pagination and search features included.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `th` indexing when you do `$('th').each(function(col)`

`col` is index of all `th` in page which doesn't work well when indexing in the cell sorting

Following approach works

```
$('table').each(function(col) {
   var sortOrder
  $(this).find('th').click(function() {
    var col = $(this).index()
   // all same after this
```

Suggest you get rid of repetitive calls to `$(this)` by caching variables for `$th`,  `$table`,`$siblings` etc

Note you can also append whole array without `each` also

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gyfoousf/16/)**</kbd>

Comment: was about to post solution similar to @Louys Patrice Bessette, this one iss better. +1 vote up for this

Answer (score 2):

The `col` index returned by `.each` is wrong for the second table...
Since that index is based on the `th` collection for the whole page, regardless of the table in which it is in.

So wrap your function with:

```
$("table").each(function(){
```

And then use `$(this).find('th').each(function(col) {`.
The rest is unchanged.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/zu59qj0f/)

Answer (score 1):

No need for extra library or plugin for this.
The problem you have is that you have two tables and you r walking all 'th's and save their number in col, so the variable col is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
in the second table you are searching for td under th which is equal to col in your case 3,4 or 5. But these doesn't exists.
You only have to normlaize your col variable. For example adding this:

```
arrData.sort(function(a, b) {
   col = col >= 3 ? col-3 : col; // add this line
   var val1 = $(a).find('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
   var val2 = $(b).find('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
   ....
```

Fiddle updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/gyfoousf/15/